# Trying to get true or false from a function wont do anything

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Im trying to call a function in order to know if a company has reaached the maximum allowed registrations but everytime I call it it wont print anything.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

```js
getMaxRegs(company: string) {
    var snapshotMaxRegs = this.db.object(`companies/${company}/maxregs`,{ preserveSnapshot: true})

    return snapshotMaxRegs.map(snapshot => {
        console.log('maxRegs = '+ snapshot.val())
        return snapshot.val();
    });
}

getCountRegs(company: string){
    var snapshotCountRegs = this.db.object(`companies/${company}/countregs`,{ preserveSnapshot: true})

    return snapshotCountRegs.map(snapshot => {
        console.log('currRegs = '+ snapshot.val())
        return snapshot.val();
    });
}

maxRegsReached(company: string){

    return Observable.forkJoin([
        this.getCountRegs(company),
        this.getMaxRegs(company)
    ]).map((joined)=>{
        let countRegs = joined[0];
        let maxRegs = joined[1];

        return countRegs >= maxRegs;
    })
}
```

Now I to subscribe to maxRegsReached to get the results but it wont print anything...

```js
    this.maxRegsReached('01').subscribe(result => {
            console.log(result) //true or false
    })
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Does your code reach to the `return countRegs >= maxRegs;` line?

Comment: Do you see the results of other `console.log`s?

Comment: From the documentation, I understand when using `forkjoin` if one of the observables hasn't emit any value, your `subscription` won't be called.
Check here https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html and here http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

Comment: Yes, Im able to output when I enter maxRegsReached but not before the return... Also both of the observables returns value.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
this.maxRegsReached('01')
    .map(response => response)
    .subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result) //true or false
    })
```

Comment: Same thing, it enters the function but no output :/

Comment: Do the 'maxRegs' and 'getCountRegs' console logs fire? What's their output? If you change the maxRegsReached console to '      console.log("Result:" ,result) //true or false', do you see 'Result:' on the console?